# TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-sleuth, embedded-tomcat-8

I am migrating maven based spring application to spring boot 2.0.4.RELEASE. Application has dependency on Apache CXF, Security, Sleuth, mongoDB, and RabbitMQ along with a few other libraries.
Build is successful using command mvn clean install, but when I am trying to run the spring boot application using command `mvn spring-boot:run`, it is failing with following error:
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is `org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat`. Looking at other few similar questions, I have tried wiring in javax servlet api from `spring-boot-starter-jersey` , and commenting out 'jackson' libraries, but no success so far.

I referred migration page from [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#embedded-containers-package-structure), but couldn't figure out a way to do so.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.hbo.esp.MyApplication.main (MyApplication.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize (TomcatWebServer.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init> (TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.hbo.esp.MyApplication.main (MyApplication.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions (TomcatWebServer.java:172)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize (TomcatWebServer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init> (TomcatWebServer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer (TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at com.hbo.esp.MyApplication.main (MyApplication.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.073 s
```